# Make condition on MySQL table LEFT JOIN "ON"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

Here is my left join query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table1` as t1
LEFT JOIN `table2` as t2
on t2.table1_id = t1.id // here joins all id,s of table1 in table 2.
where t1.master_id = 72
```

Here I want joins only like `t2.table1_id` = first id of `t1.id` fetched from `t1.master_id`.

**returning TABLE**

```
ID          master_id   t1_name   t2_name
3            72           A         A1
3            72           B         A2
6            72           C         A3
6            72           D         A4
```

**EXPECTING TABLE**

```
ID          master_id   t1_name   t2_name
3            72           A         A1
3            72           B         A2
6            72           C
6            72           D
```

expecting table returns only first id based result in column t2_name!

If the first id (first array id element) of `t1.id = 3` then query look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table1` as t1
LEFT JOIN `table2` as t2
on t2.table1_id = t1.id  AND t2.table1_id = 3
where t1.master_id = 72
```

but how we made this dynamically with single query?

Comment: Can you please add example data and expected output?It is still a bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case to check if the master_id and ID are equal. This statement returns the t2_name when ID and master_id are equal, otherwise it returns just an empty string. This might not be the fastest option when you use this query on a large database.
I hope this is what you are looking for :)

```
   SELECT ID, master_id, t1_name, t2_name =
   CASE ID
       WHEN master_id THEN t2_name
       ELSE ""
   END
   FROM 'table1' as t1
   JOIN 'table2' as t2
   ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
   WHERE master_id = 72
```

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a LEFT JOIN, You will only get NULL (empty slots) instead of A3 and A4 IF there is no match on table2 for the last two rows of table1. It would be very helpful if you could show us some of the data in both tables.